# What does griefing mean?

Tags: security, plasma, terminology

Not referring to the definition in the dictionary. In the context of blockchains and Ethereum in particular, the term "grief" has been used repeatedly in a host of scenarios: ethresear.ch, Plasma calls, Twitter conversations etc.

Answer (score 10):

This question is about the *verb* "to grief" rather than the *noun* "grief".

The latter is presumably what lots of people are currently feeling due to the drop in cryptocurrency prices.

The former, which is what you're asking about, is when someone uses a system in an unexpected way to create what other users of the system might call an attack. **Such an attack doesn't benefit the attacker, but does make using the system more difficult for the victim.** (i.e. It causes them grief [noun].)

It's a common term in computer games, where the person performing the griefing is referred to as the [griefer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Griefer).

For an example in the Ethereum world, take a look at the [Insufficient Gas Griefing](https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/known_attacks/#insufficient-gas-griefing) attack.